# Using an Observable to create Charts with Chart.JS in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-charts

Currently I am trying to get a Chart to work using Angular and Chart.JS .

Current Problem is that I don't get my Observable into the Chart data no Matter what i do.

`error TS2339: Property 'cool_data' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.`

My first thought is that the Observable takes a little while to get some Data and will need some time to finish ( roughly 50k data sets ). That is probably why the error occurs, because it is empty at the point where the Chart is created. Someone got an idea how to get my Observable into there or other solutions?

Currently the Service function im using is looking like the following.

```
...
  getData(id: number): Observable<Data[]> {
          return this.http.get<Data[]>(this.dataUrl + id);
                  console.log(this.http.get<Data[]>(this.dataUrl));
                  }
}
```

And my Component like this. As a reminder i tried putting `data: this.data.cool_data` but get the above error.

```
...
data: Data[];
  getData(): void{
  const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.coolService.getData(id)
                .subscribe(data => this.data = data);
  }

  goBack(): void{
   this.location.back();
   }


  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getData();
  }

lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: this.data.cool_data, label: 'Crude oil prices' },
  ];

  lineChartLabels: Label[] = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'];

  lineChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
  };

  lineChartColors: Color[] = [
    {
      borderColor: 'black',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.28)',
    },
  ];

  lineChartLegend = true;
  lineChartPlugins = [];
  lineChartType = 'line';
 }
```

The HTML file for the component:

```
<div *ngIf="data">
<div style="display: block;">
  <canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
    [datasets]="lineChartData"
    [labels]="lineChartLabels"
    [options]="lineChartOptions"
    [colors]="lineChartColors"
    [legend]="lineChartLegend"
    [chartType]="lineChartType"
    [plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't co-relate with the error. Based on the error, presumably you've assigned an observable to the `this.data` variable. But in the code, you're correctly assigning the response obtained from the HTTP request. Also in the service you say the response type is `Data[]`, so an array of type `Data`. A property called `cool_data` (or any property) cannot exist directly on an array.

Comment: Yes Sorry i posted the working version. Now take a look at the data inside the Chart. How do i assign the values of my Data array to data in my chart ? Sorry for the bad questioning but im quite new to Angular.

Comment: Could you please post the output of `getData(id)` call? I think you need to extract a list of properties as an array, and more importantly, the `lineChartData` should be assigned only inside the subscription since `this.data` is asynchronous.

Comment: Yeah i use an JSON.`[{"id":1,"cool_data":"4.5","station_id":1},{...}]`

Comment: I've posted an answer. Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment that `this.data = [{"id":1,"cool_data":"4.5","station_id":1},{...}]`, you could use array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to create an array of `cool_data` values. Also the `lineChartData` should be assigned inside the HTTP subscription since `this.data` is asynchronous.

Try the following

```js
data: Data[];
lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [];     // <-- don't assign the value here
lineChartLabels: Label[] = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'];
lineChartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
};
lineChartColors: Color[] = [
  { borderColor: 'black', backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.28)' },
];
lineChartLegend = true;
lineChartPlugins = [];
lineChartType = 'line';

getData(): void {
  const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.coolService.getData(id).subscribe(
    response => {
      this.data = response;
      this.lineChartData.push({             // <-- push value to `lineChartData`
        data: response.map(item => item.cool_data),  
        label: 'Crude oil prices'
      });
    },
    error => { }
  );
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getData();
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks, but now im getting the following error ` error TS2322: Type '{ data: number[]; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataSets[]'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'data' does not exist in type 'ChartDataSets[]'.

45  data: response.map(item => +item.cool_data),

`

Comment: @dejanero: Yes that was my mistake. I wrongfully assigned the object instead of pushing the object to the array. I've since edited the code. Please see if it works now.

Comment: Looks good :) went through without error. @Michael one more question. How do i do the same with the labels?

Comment: @dejanero: Where would like to extract the labels from? The `data` that you've showed doesn't contain any label. And since `lable` is a property for each item of the `lineChartData` array, you could access it directly. Something like `{ data: response..., label: response.label }`.

Comment: i wanted to label them by they're id. So that i got on my Y-Axis my Data and it is plotted by id. Does't make much sense in any real use but im keen on learning how it works. @Michael D

Comment: `lineChartLabels: Label[] = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'];` Basically i want to change this to be my ID's @Michael D